# Descargar PDF desde WebView app Xamarin Visual Studio

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, webview

Buen día,
tengo una app Android desarrollada con Xamarin desde Visual Studio,
la misma llama a una página web desde un WebView,
el problema se me da en que, desde la página con un LinkButton se descarga un pdf,
pero desde la aplicación no me funciona esta característica.
Abriendo la página desde PC, o exploradores celulares, si funciona correctamente.

MainPage:
namespace NombreAPP
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
WebViewInfi.Source = "linkweb";
}
}
}

MainActivity:
namespace NombreAPP.Droid
{
[Activity(Label = "NombreAPP", Icon = "@mipmap/ic_Icono", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

```
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No utilices negrilla en la pregunta parece que estuvieras gritando. Puedes agregar el código de lo que has intentado?

Comment: Bienvenido por favor agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, es impotante revisar [ask], saludos

Comment: @Bicho, ahí pasé el código con el cual visualizo la web, como explicaba el problema se me da para abrir un pdf dentro de la web desde la app.

Comment: Ahí le corregí la pregunta, si me van a poder acesorar?

Answer (score 0):

Sube el pdf a google drive y luego usa xamarin para abrirlo con el link.

Solo necesitarías estas lineas de código:

```
var url = "https://drive.google.com/fileel(link de tu pdf)";
Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
```

Como se explica en este video de Youtube: https://youtu.be/kJKrz7g1PM0

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/350235)